# Combining instrumented JUnit4 Test with Target apk into one apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests, android-instrumentation

When I create a new project in Android Studio with no activity, and I want to run the default instrumented test that is created in the project, I have to:

install both the target apk: app-debug.apk , and app-debug-androidTest.apk. and run the proper adb shell am command.

Since there is no activity, I am not even sure what 'app-debug.apk' would do.

Is there a way of building this application/instrumented test, such that there is only one apk. This feels like a gradle/android studio question, and I am admittedly new to both.

Comment: this defeats the idea of instrumentation.

Comment: Your comment is neither helpful to solving my problem, nor do you explain your premise in any sort of way, please reconsider how you use stack overflow